# Duration of MP3 files in metadata

Tags: audio, music, metadata, mp3, id3-tag

For language study, I frequently download nine MP3 files from several different sources, and import them into Music.app.  All are monaural (i.e., single track).  Music.app shows the wrong duration for most of them.  Most of the wrong ones show a duration **approximately** half what it should be, but further off than rounding error.  [eyeD3](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [exiftool](https://exiftool.org) also show wrong durations but significantly different from what Music.app shows.  Finder shows the correct duration.

If I play one of these tracks with Music.app, the progress bar goes to the end as if the displayed duration were correct, and stays there while the track continues to play.

If I edit the audio with [Amadeus Pro](https://hairersoft.com/pro.html) to remove excessive silence at each end, and save it, eyeD3 and exiftool will then show the correct duration.  Music.app will correct it if/when I play the file or Get Info on the corrected file.  (Amadeus shows the correct value before editing.)

**How are Music.app, eyeD3, and exiftool getting durations that are not only wrong but different from each other?**  Is there a way to correct the duration without editing the file?  (Playing it before editing does not correct the value in any of the three tools.)

Comment: In regard to exiftool and duration, see [this Github response](https://github.com/exiftool/exiftool/issues/160#issuecomment-1293946184) from exiftool's author.

Comment: Perhaps the other apps do something similar.  Whatever it is, Amadeus manages to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you ask "how"...

An mp3 file mostly consists of blocks of music/sound. Each block has a header. The header describes exactly how the music in the block is encoded, and from that an MP3 player knows exactly how many bytes and how many microseconds that block is, and how to play it back. Note that every single block of sound could be in a different format, and your MP3 player will handle this.

In principle, that's enough information to determine exactly how many seconds the whole file is. It just reads the file from the start, figures out where music blocks start, calculates their time and adds them all up. So no metadata is needed at all except for the headers of these blocks.

In order to start playback instantly (especially for streaming), there is often metadata which describes how long the file is in seconds. The MP3 player will trust this. So if the metadata is wrong, it will show the wrong results. The metadata can also contain positions, for example how many bytes into the file do the blocks at 1 second, 2 seconds and so on start, so the MP3 player can jump to any point quickly.

As an alternative, the MP3 player can make guesses. Say your file starts with 20 blocks at 128 kilobit, stereo, fixed rate. Then the MP3 player might guess that the whole file is 128 kilobit, stereo, fixed rate. Then it knows the length of the file in bytes and calculates how many seconds long the whole file would be. If the guess is wrong, your output is wrong. For example if the file changes bitrate from black to block. If two MP3 players guess the time incorrectly and in a different way, then these players will show different incorrect file lengths.

If the problem is metadata, then you can remove the metadata. Without metadata, the player should read all the blocks and calculate the time. Even for 50 MB / one hour, that would be fast. If the player doesn't play correctly without metadata, then the only thing you can do is add correct metadata.

Comment: THe files downloaded had no metadata, and I added a lot.  But I did not add anything related to duration.  Maybe Amadeus added that.